# ProgressDialog crash

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a piece of code which shows progressdialog in an activity .

```
m_oProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", "");
```

but i counter a crash at this line which has error log as follows..
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token

```
android.os.BinderProxy@419743f8 is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:517)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
```

I even tried This instead if MyActivity.this and getBaseContext() anyone ?

```
i have a function which shows a progress dialog... i first check whether its showing or not ...if not i will show..

 private void showProgressDialog()
    {
        if( (m_oProgressDialog!=null) && (!this.isFinishing()) )
        {
            if( m_oProgressDialog.isShowing() == false )
                m_oProgressDialog.show();
        }
        else
        {
            m_oProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", "");
        }
 }
```

Comment: Can we have complete code please ! ?

Comment: Sounds like you are calling this as a field variable... Call it when you have a valid Context in `onCreate()` or later.

Comment: @user1340801 post full java code and give more information.

Comment: check `if ((MyActivity.this).isFinishing() == false) ` before showing ProgressDialog

Comment: When do you call `showDialogProgress()`? Also your current `isFinishing()` logic is faulty...